# Widget Development - Displaying dropdown content

Tags: widgets, front-end, dropdown

I'm using the following code to create a widget to select a post from a dropdown - which works fine in the backend, but I can't figure out how to display this on the frontend...

```
<?php 

class RandomPostWidget extends WP_Widget
{
  function RandomPostWidget()
  {
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'RandomPostWidget', 'description' => 'Displays a featured post' );
    $this->WP_Widget('RandomPostWidget', 'Featured Homepage Post', $widget_ops);
  }

  function form($instance)
  {
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '' ) );
    $title = $instance['title'];
?>
  <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title: <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($title); ?>" /></label></p>

  <select name="page_id" id="page_id">
 <?php
 global $post;
 $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1,'category' => 5);
 $posts = get_posts($args);
 foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <option value="<? echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>

<?php
  }

  function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
  {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
    return $instance;
  }

  function widget($args, $instance)
  {
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

    echo $before_widget;
    $title = empty($instance['title']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);   

    if (!empty($title))
      echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;;

    // WIDGET CODE GOES HERE
    echo "<h1></h1>";

    echo $after_widget;
  }

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("RandomPostWidget");') );


?>
```

I'm probably overlooking something simple - but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `'numberposts' => -1` can create a dropdown with 1,000,000 entries. Not a good idea. :)

Comment: Yeh, you're right - but it's also linked to category & for now there's only a few posts, so I'm not too concerned with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$instance['page_id']` should be the post ID of the selected post. So …

```
function widget($args, $instance)
{
    $post = get_post( $instance['page_id'] );
    echo $post->post_content; // you should add the common filters here
    var_dump( $post ); // more data
}
```

… should be a good start.

To save the last value in the configuration form use `selected()`:

```
foreach( $posts as $post )
{
    setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <option value="<? echo $post->ID; ?>" <?php 
        selected( $instance['page_id'], $post->ID ); 
        ?>><?php the_title(); ?></option>
<?php 
}
```

Comment: Thanks - Which bit does this go in? I can't work out how to get the content from the post ID...

Comment: @Dave See my update.

Comment: aha - thanks! I've (or rather You...) have nearly cracked it.

I've tidied up the code a bit - but I just have one more problem. When I select anything from the dropdown menu and click "save", it always reverts back to the top selection.

Is this a problem with my $instance? (http://pastebin.com/dzfV3RH5)

Comment: @Dave See last update.

Comment: I can see how I missed that part in my tidying up, but now get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION on line 58`... (http://pastebin.com/PbgmaHUx)

Comment: @Dave Not sure what this is. Looks like a separate issue. You should avoid `create_function()`; that’s bad style.

Comment: OKay - thanks for the help! I marked it as answered cus it helped me out loads. I just got a small way to go now. Thanks!